# unfinished multithreaded port scanner not working (getting bus error and ports wont open)

Tags: c, networking

```
// gnu licensed
// by unidef
// --

// system libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// multithreading libraries
#include <pthread.h>

// networking libraries
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

// defines
#define PORT_END_NUMBER 65535

#define SOCKET_MAIN_THREAD 0

// globals
int threads;

struct sockaddr_in *temp;
char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
int port;
int status[5];
int port_range[2];


// future variables
int global_port;
int local_port;

// ! code begin

void NET_INIT(){
  free(temp);
  status[0] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  temp = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  temp->sin_family = AF_INET;
  temp->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
}

int *ScanPort(char *ip, int port, int *Connect){
  int *C;
  C = malloc(sizeof(int));
  Connect = malloc(sizeof(int));
  temp = NULL;
  free(temp);
  NET_INIT();
  temp->sin_port = htons(port);
  *C = connect(status[SOCKET_MAIN_THREAD], (struct sockaddr*)&temp, sizeof(temp));
  return C;
}

int Scan(){
  int NB;
  int *S;
  pthread_t local_id;

  NB = port_range[0];
  while (NB < port_range[1]){
    pthread_create(&local_id, NULL, S = ScanPort(ip, NB, 0), (void *)&local_id);
    printf("ip: %s ; port: %d ; connect() status: %d\n", ip, NB, *S);
    NB++;
  }
  return 0;
}
int NewportHelp(){
  printf("newport .1 by unidef\n");
  printf("multithreaded network scanner\n");
  printf("./newport ip port-range-start port-range-end threads\n");
  return 0;
}

void Print_Variables(){
  printf("\n*ip = %s\nport_range = %d - %d\nthreads = %d\n", ip, port_range[0], port_range[1], threads);
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  struct hostent *host;
  long x;
  if (argc != 5){
    printf("beta software, please input right variables\n");
    NewportHelp();
    return 1;
  }

  host = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
  ip = host->h_addr_list;
  port_range[0] = atoi(argv[2]);
  port_range[1] = atoi(argv[3]) + 1;
  threads = atoi(argv[4]);
  printf("data successfully allocated\n");
  printf("starting network scan on %s from port(s) %d to %d using %d threads\n", ip, port_range[0], port_range[1], threads);
  Scan();
  Print_Variables();

  return 0;
}
```

output data:

jons-MacBook-Pro:dev jon$ ./a.out 23.226.68.178 78 83 1
data successfully allocated
starting network scan on nP҅ from port(s) 78 to 84 using 1 threads
ip: nP҅ ; port: 78 ; connect() status: -1
ip: nP҅ ; port: 79 ; connect() status: -1
Bus error: 10
jons-MacBook-Pro:dev jon$

anyone know whats wrong? dont get too technical, i taught myself c

Comment: At the very least, you should scan both TCP and UDP ports. I believe Linux has a working version of SCTP, but not Windows, so it is your choice about scanning the ports of that protocol.

Comment: ah never mind, ill just rewrite it